# How to align some text right and some text below an image with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, responsive-design, frontend

[image]

I'm trying to do this with Bootstrap, so far I was able to put the Marketplace next to the logo with the `d-inline` class.

My problems are that the market place and the logo aren't vertical aligned, and that the text below doesn't align quite well, it looks like a paragraph with lots of breaks on it. How can I achieve this that is shown on the image?

```css
.marketplace {
        background-color: #5960CB;
        width: 100%;
        height: 50%;
        list-style-type: none;
    }
 .containerMarket p {
        color: white;
        font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
        margin-left: 5px;
        margin-top: 10px;
    }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="marketplace col-sm-12">
        <div class="container containerMarket col-sm-4">
            <img src="img/fullLogoWhite.png" width="150" class="d-inline"> <p class="d-inline">Marketplace</p>
            <p>High quality items created by our global community.</p>
            <p><span>65,478</span> Products | <span>65,478</span> Members | <span>65,478</span> Vendors</p>
        </div>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You must use Bootstrap vertical alignment:

> ```
>   <td class="align-baseline">baseline</td>
> ```

[Documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/vertical-align/)

Comment: So I should do it as a table instead of divs?

Comment: No. I have put the example of the documentation, but you can use vertical align in other elements: div, img... https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/v/vertical-align/

Answer (score 0):

```css
.marketplace {
        background-color: #5960CB;
        width: 100%;
        height: 50%;
        list-style-type: none;
    }
 .containerMarket p {
        color: white;
        font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
        margin-left: 5px;
        margin-top: 10px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;        
    }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="marketplace col-sm-12">
        <div class="container containerMarket">
        <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
            <img src="img/fullLogoWhite.png" width="150" class="d-inline"> 
            <p class="d-inline">Marketplace</p>
        </div>

<p class="small">High quality items created by our global community.</p>
            <p class="small"><span>65,478</span> Products | <span>65,478</span> Members | <span>65,478</span> Vendors</p>
        </div>
```

[image]

Comment: It made 'market place' too far from the image but with adding "align-item-bottom" to Market place i fixed it, thank you so much :)